# Why is this code throwing "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object" after it has run for a while?

Tags: pandas, image-processing, jupyter-notebook

[Here's a displayable segment of the head of the dataframe I'm working with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONQgG.png)

## This is in a Jupyter Notebook!

I'm trying to populate an empty column (full of np.nan) of baseData called "Average Colour." Each element of this column represents the average colour of the image loaded from its respective "Icon URL."

*Here's my code*:

```
def compute_average_image_color(img):
    width, height = img.size
    r_total = 0
    g_total = 0
    b_total = 0
    count = 0
    for x in range(0, width):
        for y in range(0, height):
            r, g, b = img.getpixel((x,y))
            r_total += r
            g_total += g
            b_total += b
            count += 1
    return (r_total/count, g_total/count, b_total/count)

def get_average_color(URL):
    if URL != np.nan:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(URL, "local.jpg")
        with Image.open("local.jpg") as img:
            img = img.resize((50,50)) #To make this run MUCH faster.
            return compute_average_image_color(img)

baseData["Average Colour"] = baseData["Icon URL"].apply(lambda x: get_average_color(x))
```

compute_average_image_color() is not mine, and I know it works.
As far a I can tell, get_average_color() works as intended. This code runs for 37 iterations before crashing out with:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-1675bd6f49ad> in <module>
     41             return compute_average_image_color(img)
     42 
---> 43 baseData["Average Colour"] = baseData["Icon URL"].apply(lambda x: get_average_color(x))
     44 
     45 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3589             else:
   3590                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3591                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3592 
   3593         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-51-1675bd6f49ad> in <lambda>(x)
     41             return compute_average_image_color(img)
     42 
---> 43 baseData["Average Colour"] = baseData["Icon URL"].apply(lambda x: get_average_color(x))
     44 
     45 

<ipython-input-51-1675bd6f49ad> in get_average_color(URL)
     39         with Image.open("local.jpg") as img:
     40             img = img.resize((50,50)) #To make this run MUCH faster.
---> 41             return compute_average_image_color(img)
     42 
     43 baseData["Average Colour"] = baseData["Icon URL"].apply(lambda x: get_average_color(x))

<ipython-input-51-1675bd6f49ad> in compute_average_image_color(img)
     27     for x in range(0, width):
     28         for y in range(0, height):
---> 29             r, g, b = img.getpixel((x,y))
     30             r_total += r
     31             g_total += g

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

I've looked around my spreadsheet, and nothing is special about index 37 or the ones around it (35-39), so I'm not sure why this only happens after 37 runs. The index in question has the Icon URL "https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple4/v4/e6/88/05/e688059e-2809-4f8f-9f78-cb7ceb7b461b/source/512x512bb.jpg", which doesn't seem to be special in any way.

Further, this sheet is 17000 indexes long, and Jupyter Notebook only seems to be going at 1 a second. Is that just Jupyter being artificially slow? I sure hope so, since that means I could run it a lot faster in a *.py*.

Answer (score 0):

There are chances that url might be `invalid`. If the url is invalid, the resulting image will be of `2 dimensions` from PIL. So to be on safer side, convert the image to numpy array and use the vectorized approach like in below, which is way faster than for loops.

```
import numpy as np 
def compute_average_image_color(img):
    img = np.array(img)
    try:
        r_mean = img[:,:,0].mean()
        g_mean = img[:,:,1].mean()
        b_mean = img[:,:,2].mean()
        return (r_mean,g_mean,b_mean)
    except:
        mean = img.mean()
        return (mean,mean,mean)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it! I have no idea how you figured out what was wrong. I swear you're a god damn wizard. 
Do you have any idea how to get this to run at more than 1-2 indexes a second? I've already launched the notebook with "jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e12" just in case.

Comment: @sproga2 this depends on your internet speed as well, since you are downloading the images. If the image is too large and internet speed is limited it cant be helped.

Comment: @sproga2 if you found the answer helpful, do consider accepting it.